# Estimating signal-to-noise ratio after smoothing data and covariance estimates

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, covariance-matrix, smoothing, noise

I have data for two variables, let's say $A$ and $B$, which have distributions that are roughly centered at 0. I am computing a value, let's say $C = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}$, from this data. I also have a covariance matrix for my data: $\sigma_{AA}$, $\sigma_{AB}$, $\sigma_{BB}$. I know how to estimate the error on my value of interest, $\sigma_{C}$, from this data.

Now I want to smooth this data to obtain better SNR on $C$, i.e. $C/\sigma_C$. I Gaussian smooth $A$ and $B$ by convolving with a Gaussian kernel $w$, and I smooth the elements of the covariance matrix $\sigma_{AA}$, etc, by convolving with $w^2$. When I compute $SNR_{smoothed} = C_{smoothed} / \sigma_{C_{smoothed}}$, however, the value is lower than the SNR of the un-smoothed data. Presumably this is because smoothing $A$ and $B$ pushes them toward 0, whereas $\sigma_{AA}$, $\sigma_{AB}$, etc are always positive values. What am I doing wrong?

How can I correctly compute an SNR for an estimator computed from smoothed data, where (in the actual case) the estimator depends on the covariance information?

Comment: do you have the signal? you need a signal to calculate signal to noise

Comment: I want to know how to estimate SNR on C

Comment: a lot of things can go wrong, e.g. you may choose a wide kernel window, and it'll completely obliterate your signal. i don't understand how you calculate signal though

Comment: sorry, I am sure my language is wrong here. C are computed from measurements of A and B. How to calculate 'signal' from this? I thought SNR would be C/sigma_C but is this wrong?

Comment: C seems to be the noise and signal together

Comment: thanks. so what to do? I need to estimate SNR for the smoothed data

Comment: Can you show the plots?

Comment: I need to calculate the SNR at low resolution of the estimator described here: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014MNRAS.439.4048P